# Pyschool: Topic 1

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and i jumped right into python 3. However i am trying to use the learning practices from pyschools.com. I have run into a question that deals with using strings. They want this result: `"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."`. In Python 3 I can just type this out literal using the `"""` before and after. however in Python 2 that same line comes out as `\'"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don\'t know how long it will take."\'`. How do I format this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem; your python interpreter is echoing the string back to you in a manner that can be pasted back into the interpreter.

Use `print()` instead if you want to just print the string value instead of the string literal:

```
>>> '''"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."'''
'"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don\'t know how long it will take."'
>>> print('''"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."''')
"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."
```

Note that there is no difference between python versions in that regard; python 3 behaves in exactly the same manner.

Comment: Thank you, i used the ''' instead of """